# Conditional Rails serializers for Show but not Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, activerecord, active-model-serializers

I have a number of serializers associated with one of my models (`Game`) that query several other tables when the route is hit. I only need those serializers to query when I hit my `games#show` action, because when they fire off on my `games#index`, it takes way too long to query the database with the serializers when all I really need is the name of the Game instance.

I read through a few other threads here that suggested I could include params to pass from my controller to my serializer with `@instance_options` and then build a conditional method in my serializer to determine whether or not the serializers should be applied, and landed on this:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @games = Game.all
        render json: @games, flag: "restrict"
    end

    def show
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
        render json: @game
    end
end
```

```
class GameSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :users, if: condition
  has_many :groups, if: condition
  has_many :interests, if: condition

  def condition
    @instance_options[:flag] != "restrict"
  end

end
```

The issue is that my `condition` method is resolving as false regardless of the value of `flag`, and will even do so if `flag` is completely left out. I tried tossing a byebug inside of the `condition` method but never hit it, and also was not able to see anything `puts` out from there when I gave that a shot. Clearly I'm not attacking this the right way - any ideas?

Comment: An if or unless option can make an attribute conditional. It takes a symbol of a method name on the serializer, or a lambda literal. -> Replace `has_many :users, if: condition` With `has_many :users, if: :condition`

Comment: THANK YOU! Knew i was missing something small!